# "Подкованный" знаниями

Tags: фразеология

Когда мы говорим о ком-то, кто эрудирован в каком-то вопросе, то зачастую употребляем выражение "Он очень подкован в этом вопросе". Например, вот попалась фраза в новостях: "В следующем раунде Маррей встретится с Денисом Истоминым. — Технически он (Истомин) очень подкован".
Так вот, интересно, почему, говоря о знаниях по какому-то предмету, мы вспоминаем лошадиную атрибутику? Откуда пошло это выражение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знания для человека, как подковы для лошади. Вроде бы можно и без них обойтись, но с ними продвинешься дальше. Потому знающего человека и называют подкованным в той или иной области.